# C++ linker problems with static method

Tags: c++, linker, static-methods

I'm writing a Vector3D class that calls a static method on a VectorMath class to perform a calculation. When I compile, I get this:

```
bash-3.1$ g++ VectorMath.cpp Vector3D.cpp
/tmp/cc5cAPia.o: In function `main':
Vector3D.cpp:(.text+0x4f7): undefined reference to 'VectorMath::norm(Vector3D*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code:

**VectorMath.h:**

```
#ifndef VECTOR3D_H
#include "Vector3D.h"
#endif

class VectorMath {
    public:
    static Vector3D* calculatePerpendicularVector(Vector3D*, Vector3D*);
    static Vector3D* norm(Vector3D*);
    static double length(Vector3D*);
};
```

**VectorMath.cpp**

```
#include "VectorMath.h"
Vector3D* norm(Vector3D* vector) { // can't be found by linker
    // do vector calculations
    return new Vector3D(xHead, yHead, zHead, xTail, yTail, zTail);
}
// other methods
```

**Vector3D.cpp**

```
#include "Vector3D.h"
#include "VectorMath.h"
// ...
// vector implementation
// ...
int main(void) {
    Vector3D* v = new Vector3D(x, y, z);
    Vector3D* normVector = VectorMath::norm(v); // error here
}
```

Why can't the linker find the `VectorMath::norm` method? At first glance I'd think that I'd need to declare norm like this:

```
Vector3D* VectorMath::norm(Vector3D* vector) {
```

but that doesn't help either...

Comment: This: "but that doesn't help either..." is not enough information. What does that mean? Same errors, different errors?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're missing this:

```
//VectorMath.cpp
#include "VectorMath.h"

             |
             V - here
Vector3D* VectorMath::norm(Vector3D* vector)
{
    ...
}
```

The `norm` function is part of `VectorMath::`. Without that, you just have a free function.

---

This is more about your design, but why are you using pointers to everything? This is much cleaner:

```
class VectorMath {
    public:
    static Vector3D norm(const Vector3D&);
};
```

Take references, you're in C++ so don't write C code. What happens when I call this?

```
VectorMath::norm(0); // null
```

It will either crash, you have to put in a check, in which case, what should it return? This is all cleaned up by using references.

Also, why not just make these members of the `Vector3D` class?

```
Vector3D* v = new Vector3D(x, y, z);
v->norm(); // normalize would be better, in my opinion
```

Lastly, stack-allocate things. Your code right now has a memory leak:

```
int main(void) {
    Vector3D* v = new Vector3D(x, y, z);
    Vector3D* normVector = VectorMath::norm(v); 

    // delete v;
    // ^ you're not deleting it!
}
```

Change it to this, and use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) concepts:

```
int main(void) {
    Vector3D v(x, y, z);
    Vector3D* normVector = VectorMath::norm(v);

    // delete v;
    // ^ you're not deleting it!
}
```

And by making `norm` a member function you end up with the very clean code:

```
int main(void) {
    Vector3D v(x, y, z);
    Vector3D normVector(v.norm());
}
```

No pointers, no leaks, all sexy.

Comment: OK, thank you, that seems to work. I swear I tried that before and it failed - but it is working now...Thanks for the pointers about the memory leak thing...I guess I'll ask a new question about those...

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined `Vector3D::norm` method in `VectorMath.cpp`. Instead you've defined a global function named `norm`. What you need to do is qualify the method name in the definition:

```
Vector3D* Vector3D::norm(Vector3D* vector)
```

Comment: You're 24 seconds faster than me. :[

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3D* VectorMath::norm(Vector3D* vector) { // can't be found by linker
    // do vector calculations
    return new Vector3D(xHead, yHead, zHead, xTail, yTail, zTail);
}
```