# C++ calling static method from another class in main.cpp using Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, static-methods

I have a project containing:

```
main.cpp
plainground.cpp
plainground.h
```

The project is set up in Eclipse CDT and I am using GLUT (a OpenGL library)

My goal was to call a function from plainground in "main.cpp".

So this is how my plainground.h looks like:

```
#ifndef PLAINGROUND_H_
#define PLAINGROUND_H_

class plainground {

public:
    plainground();
    static void set_point_values(int index, double x1,double x2,double x3);
    static void calculate_plain_xuv();
    static void prind_plain_xuv();
};

#endif /* PLAINGROUND_H_ */
```

And here the part where I tried to call a function:

```
...
#include "plainground.h"
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    plainground::set_point_values(1,10,5,0); //
}
```

So when I'm building the Project I get following error:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o "MartinProject"  ./main.o ./plainground.o   -lglut -lGLU -lGL
./main.o:main.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'plainground::set_point_values(int, double, double, double)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm thankful for every help,

Martin

Comment: show the `plainground.cpp` file

Comment: You *do* define (implement) `plainground::set_point_values` somewhere in one of the files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ linker problems with static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210282/c-linker-problems-with-static-method)

Comment: you need to declare this function : static void set_point_values(int index, double x1,double x2,double x3) with a body.